# Highlighting the child in a item list on a navigation drawer (sidebar) vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

there are similar questinos out there but none of them address this problem using vuetify/vue.

i have a list in my navigation drawer. it has a couple options and i when you click on an option it will change the page. i was hoping to have the option highlighted when you change the page (so you can see which page you are on).

i've tried messing with the css classes, using

```
.v-application a {
    color: #1976d2;
}
```

and a few others; and while it will change the color of the tab, I want it to be transparent color until clicked upon

```
<v-navigation-drawer>   
  <v-list nav>
      <v-list-item v-for="(link, i) in links" :key="i" :to="link.to">
        <v-list-item-action>
          <v-icon class="list">{{ link.icon }}</v-icon>
        </v-list-item-action>
        <v-list-item-title v-text="link.text" class="list" />
      </v-list-item>
    </v-list>
  </v-navigation-drawer>
```

[image]

as you can see from this image, the active page that i am on (Dashboard) is not highlighted...

Comment: You can do something like `:value="$route.path === link.to"` on the `list-item`

Comment: dang, @Ohgodwhy that didn't work

Comment: Is it possible that `$route.path` and `link.to` aren't exact?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy i just checked the routes and they are exact. to me it feels like a CSS problem, but can't for the life of me get it